# Скроллинг динамических визуальных объектов

Tags: delphi

У меня есть приложение, работающее с некоторыми внешними данными. Эти данные представляют собой своеобразную базу данных, в которой содержатся структуры таблиц. Приложение считывает такую структуру, получает количество полей, их названия, тип данных, обязательность заполнения и тд. На основе этих данных динамически создаются поля заполнения (TEdit, TComboBox и тд.) и закидываются в соответствующие динамические массивы. Эти объекты отображаются на панели (TPanel). Так как объектов много и все они не вмещаются на панель, я прикрепил скроллбар и при скролле меняю свойство Top у этих объектов.

Вроде бы все удобно, но когда общее количество динамических объектов превышает 150 штук, они не могут достаточно быстро перерисоваться, и при скролле происходят неприятные тормозящие визуальные эффекты.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет более эффективный способ хранения объектов, и их скролла?

PS. не надо предлагать вместо визуальных объектов делать stringgrid, я именно от него и ухожу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ставите у всех обьектов Visible в false, обработку ведете только у тех которые попадают в область видимости хотябы частью, и у них же отображение включать, остальные игнорировать совершенно(не менять Top в описаном случае) если нужено будут описать на примере, положите в коммент тот кусок кода котрый у вас отвечает за сдвиг контролов.

Comment: допустим:

    z:= InternetObjHeigth div 100;

    for I := 0 to Length(LabelArray) - 1 do
      LabelArray[i].Top := LabelArray[i].Top - (Scrollpos*z) + (LastVerticalScrollPos*z);

Comment: Z - высота отображаемого поля
X - высота контрола
С - Отступ между контролами
A - положение скрола в пересчет на пиксели т.е. макс значение скрола = X+C*Length(LabelArray);
V- некая временная переменная.

   for I := 0 to Length(LabelArray) - 1 do
     With LabelArray[i] do
     Begin
       V := A-(I*(X+C));
       if ((V>0)and(V<Z) then 
         Begin
           Top := V;
           Visible:=True;
         end else 
         Visible := False;
     end;

Comment: Прикинул тут чуток, и советую отказаться от подобной реализации(что у вас сейчас), если необходимо именно отказаться от стринггрида в пользу множества компонентов сделайте форму на которой изначально\динамически выстроится кол-во обьектов=видимому колву записей, а по скролу из массива(не в коем случае не листа) подгружайте в них данные, для пущей красоты можно сделать кол-во видимых+1 и сдвигать их по кругу, аля анимация скролирования.Прирост скорости будет огромный из за отсутствия необходимости перебирать весь массив значений. Подробней могу в скайпе(ToRcH565) описать.

Comment: Спасибо, дали пищу для размышления.  
Однако  
>> изначально\динамически выстроится кол-во обьектов=видимому колву записей  

Если бы нужно было использовать только один вид компонентов для ввода данных, то это был бы самый оптимальный вариант, но у меня для разный полей таблицы используются разные поля ввода (TMemo, TEdit и TComboBox).  

Можно попробовать хранить в некоторых переменных номера первого и последнего компонента (они у меня пронумерованы, согласно порядку полей таблицы), и создавать объекты, которые рядом с панелью, и удалять те, которые вышли из нее при скролле.

Comment: Вы плохо ореиентируетесь в самом языке, как вам такая конструкция

    Type
     TMyDataType = record\Class\object
      Lable1 : string;
      Memo1  : StringList;
      Memo2  : Array Of String;
      combo  : record
        Text : string;
        list : array of string;
      end;
      Check  : Boolean;
      ......
     end;
    Var 
      MyDataArr : array of TMyDataType;

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач обычно используют `TScrollBox`, внутрь которого кладут панель, а компоненты на панель, при этом панель может быть любого размера и она будет прокручиваться скроллбаром.