# Скроллинг динамических объектов

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-xe3

[Скроллинг динамических визуальных объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148896/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Похожий вопрос уже был, но я, постараюсь в своем быть более конкретным в плане описания того, от чего хотелось бы избавиться. Объекты на StringGrid начитываются из базы. На экране все выглядит замечательно, все на своих местах.

Проблема в том, что при скроллинге (что мышкой, что скроллбаром) такие объекты, как чекбоксы, едиты и комбо не двигаются, а остаются на месте, в то время как сам StringGrid ползет. При остановке скролла все спрыгивают по своим местам и вроде все красиво, но очень хотелось бы убрать вот этот неприятный эффект. Дело в том, что варианты, которые рассматривались в вышеуказанном вопросе - у меня реализовано. Все инвизибл и тормозов, как таковых нет. Есть некий дискомфорт, который надобно устранить.

Comment: `DoubleBuffered` ставили на родителя всех контролов и грида?

Comment: Вроде не нашел. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не помогло. К сожалению (((

Comment: Мне казалось, что вопрос тут не в отрисовке, а скорее в привязке контролов. Как бы вот жестко привязать объект к StringGrid ? Наверное так окончательный вопрос звучать будет ?

Comment: Это уж вы решаете сами ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `TScrollBox`, внутри которого будет ваша панель, она может быть любой высоты и она будет прокручиваться скроллбаром вместе со всеми контролами без всяких костылей.

Comment: Не прокатит. Скроллбох и так появляется автоматом, так как контролов больше, чем панель. Пробовал ставить принудительный скролл, как вы советуете - ситуация не меняется. Все равно при скролле контролы ждут остановки и только потом вскакивают на свои места.